# Any tool that says how long each method takes to run?

Tags: c#, optimization, profiling

some parts of my program are way slow. and I was wondering if there is tool that i can use and for example it can tell me ok running methodA() took 100ms , etc ...or so useful info similar to that.

Comment: It's called a [Profiler](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]+profiler).

Comment: What you are looking for is called a profiler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What Are Some Good .NET Profilers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The System.Diagnostics namespace offers a helpful class called [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx), which can be used to time parts of your code (think of it as a "poor man's profiler").

This is how you would use it:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start(); // Start timing

// This is what we want to time
DoSomethingWeSuspectIsSlow();

stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("It took {0} ms.", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Comment: or, create a class that implements idisposable, which starts the timer on contruction, stops and writes on dispose.  Then you can time any block of code by wrapping it with a using statement!

Comment: Also make sure that the method has been invoked at least once before timing it, so that you don't measure the time for JIT-compilation.

Comment: @John Gardner - your construct is also v useful for getting perf timings out of a running Prod system.  Accumulate the timings for parts of the workitem with a tag that identifies them, and dump at the end of the workitem.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Visual Studio Team System there is a builtin profiler in 'Performance Tools'.  There is a ton of useful background on this at [this blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ianhu/).

I've found this extremely useful in identifying the [20% of my code that runs 80% of the time](https://web.archive.org/web/20160319034923/http://blog.optimizecode.com/2010/04/software-optimization-8020-rule-work/), and hence what I should worry about optimizing.

Another simple technique that can be surprisingly effective is to run your release code in the debugger, and interrupt it a few times (10 or so can be enough) while it's in the 'busy' state that you are trying to diagnose.  You may find recurring callstack info that directs you to the general area of concern.  Again, the 80/20 rule in effect.

Comment: +1 I've been using that interrupt method since before profilers were conceived of. I was mystified that so few people knew it. I would say it actually pinpoints the area of concern, and the 80/20 rule is more like 99.9/0.1

Comment: Sadly, that 80/20 link is particularly vacuous.

Comment: @Mike Dunlavey - do you have a better one? I will edit in if so. Thanks

Comment: References on this are alomst non-existent for some reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743504/any-references-on-dynamic-code-analysis/3745797#3745797

Comment: @Mike - is your article online?

Comment: I just emailed you a copy. I'm afraid you'll find it rather dry.

Answer (score 3):

Those kind of applications are known as "profilers"

Here's one for example: [example](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/)

Answer (score 2):

See our [SD C# Profiler](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Profilers/CSharpProfiler.html).   It can provide function timings of the function by itself and/or all of its callees.