# good resources/books on profiling software

Tags: performance, profiling, measurement

Can anyone suggest some good resources and/or books on profiling, importance of profiling, profiling techniques?

thanks

Comment: The keyword is "good". There's plenty of not-so-good stuff. here's my take on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743504/any-references-on-dynamic-code-analysis/3745797#3745797

Answer (score 0):

There is a [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0954612051) on how to use Valgrind, a GNU/Linux tool set that has a few profilers. If you wanted to learn about profiling, playing with Valgrind is a great "interactive" way to do it.